# How can I avoid merging while making a pull request?

Tags: git, merge

It has been asked to me to pull a master into a branch using `git pull -r origin master` but without merging anything, just copy and paste.

Is it possible? Doesn't pull merge everything by itself? I am really bad at Git and I can't really ask anyone else.

There are different conflicts merging.

Comment: git pull -r -B origin master
copy/paste means it will overwrite your changes because there is something wrong in your local version

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible? Doesn't pull merge everything by itself?

Yes it does, and that's exactly why you've been asked to pass `-r` option, which is a shortcut for `--rebase` (here being an option passed to `pull`, not the `rebase` command itself).

As you probably know, each commit forcibly refers to the parent one, which means that if your collaborators are doing the same, your branches would technically diverge starting from this parent commit and you'll then have to merge them again.

The `-r` option will instruct Git to perform an automatic rebase first if needed. It will first check if your branches has diverged and if so, your own specific work will be rebased on top of current state of the shared branch, enabling yourself to keep on developing as you did, then commit when the time is right.

This avoids you to write an explicit `git rebase` by yourself between, said, `master` and `origin/master` each time you want to commit for this same exact reason.

However, just like you said, it's better to have a good comprehension of Git's mechanisms first before directly rushing into this approach. It's mainly necessary when working with a workflow inherited from other SCM where the relationships between commits and ancestors don't forcibly apply.